# Delegated jQuery event not working on dynamically-added elements

Tags: jquery

I have been using a jQuery script I found here to highlight/unhighlight rows in a table when they are clicked. The script is:

```
$(".clickable-row").click(function(){
if($(this).hasClass('row-highlight'))
    $(this).removeClass('row-highlight');
else
    $(this).addClass('row-highlight').siblings().removeClass('row-highlight');
```

}

All the rows in my table have a class clickable-row.

This has been working fine for me until I introduced a table that has rows added to it dynamically when the user clicks a button.  In that table, the dynamically-added rows are not highlighted.

I'm not a jquery expert by any means but after some research I found that by using event delegation, the dynamically-added rows should be clickable, so I changed my script to this:

```
$(".clickable-row").on("click", "td", function () {

if ($(this).parent().hasClass('row-highlight')) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('row-highlight');
} else {
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('row-highlight');
    $(this).parent().addClass('row-highlight');

}
```

});

This works fine for my static table but still does not work on the dynamically-added rows.

I have checked the html for the dynamically added rows and they look like this:

```
<tr class="clickable-row">
<td>some text here</td>
<td class="hidden"><input type="text" name ="ID2" value="2"></td>
```

The html structure is exactly the same as the existing rows in the same table.  The rows are contained within  tags.

Where am I going wrong?

Edit: For some reason, the code blocks are not displaying correctly.  There is a "/tr" tag at the end of the html example but it's not showing up in the question.

Comment: .clickable-row is dynamic element, too, so, try to attach event to table (static parent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching to `.clickable-row` will bind a handler to every row which is inefficient especially on large tables. It'll be better to bind it to the table instead.

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr td', function(e) {
  alert('click')
});
```

This will click on new cells. Use just `tr` if it's the whole row you want to click instead of individual cells.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/es8rLhpt/2/

Comment: Your jsfiddle works so I will try this approach.  Do you think binding to the .clickable-row instead of the table was the problem?  My script originally bound to the tr bit it didn;t fire until I bound it to the td.

Comment: Just tried this approach and it works so accepted it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

It can work with the .click() event you just need to unbind and rebind.

So run the code you have to bind the "click" event to your table cells again for new cells that are added.

Also make sure to unbind the event listeners before binding an event listener again.

In this case

```
$(".clickable-row").unbind("click");
```

then run

```
 $(".clickable-row").click(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass('row-highlight'))
         $(this).removeClass('row-highlight');
     else
         $(this).addClass('row-highlight').siblings().removeClass('row-highlight');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I may try that if I can't figure out why the event delegation doesn't work.